# Effective way to handle redundant UI elements in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface

I have numerous activites in my Android app., and most should contain the same, relatively complex set of UI widgets on the screen's top area (lets say that its a kind of toolbar that you can find on most screens).

Right now, every screen's layout contains the markup for this toolbar, along with its logic inside every Activity's source, so it's damn redundant. Could you recommend a more efficient / less redunant way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take advantage of the `<include>` tag in the layout's xml. This will let you reuse that toolbar very easily and effectively.  As for the code I would subclass Activity and place the logic in there, then each of you activities can subclass your custom Activity class.

There are 3 very useful articles on the dev site about this topic. Here is the first one [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html)

Comment: Thank you, I used the include tag and subclassing, it's much better structured now.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom `View` object (subclass `View`) and then include it in all of your layout xml.  You can actually pass parameters, etc. just like built in views.  Then define XML for that view that will always be used when that view is drawn on the screen.  Also, this allows you to change the view and have that change populated across all of your `Activities` without having to manually modify all of the code.